# Recursively check for files with executable bit set

Tags: shell, permissions

Using the command line how can I get a listing of all files in the current directory and all sub directories that have the executable ( `+x` ) bit set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find is your friend:

```
find <path> -perm -g=x -type f
```

to find all files (-type f) with the x-bit set for the group in "path".

Answer (score 3):

Try [the cool `find` wizard](http://find.unixpin.com/): it says, `find . -perm u+x,g+x,o+x -print`

I didn't check, though, so beware!